# Selecting all top words in Python list using Counter

Tags: python, list, counter

I believe this should be pretty straightforward, but it seems I am not able to think straight to get this right.

I have a list as follows:

```
comp = [Amazon, Apple, Microsoft, Google, Amazon, Ebay, Apple, Paypal, Google]
```

I just want to print the words that occur the most. I did the following:

```
cnt = Counter(comp.split(','))
final_list = cnt.most_common(2)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
[[('Amazon', 2), ('Apple', 2)]]
```

I am not sure what parameter pass in most_common() since it could be different for each input list. So, I would like to know how I can print the top occurring words, be it 3 for one list or 4 for another. So, for the above sample, the output would be as follows:

```
[[('Amazon', 2), ('Apple', 2), ('Google',2)]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7 or Python 3.2 ? Can you give us farther details?

Comment: Amazon is repeated 3 times in the list and your output says 2.

Comment: Sorry...my bad...edited it now..Amazon, Apple and Google occurs twice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.takewhile` here:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> lis = ['Amazon', 'Apple', 'Microsoft', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'Ebay', 'Apple', 'Paypal', 'Google']
>>> c = Counter(lis)
>>> items = c.most_common()
```

Get the max count:

```
>>> max_ = items[0][1]
```

Select only those items where count = `max_`, and stop as soon as an item with less count is found:

```
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x: x[1]==max_,  items))
[('Google', 2), ('Apple', 2), ('Amazon', 2)]
```

---

You've misunderstood `Counter.most_common`:

```
most_common(self, n=None)
```

> List the `n` most common elements and their counts from the most common
>   to the least.  If `n` is None, then list all element counts.

i.e `n` is not the count here, it is the number of top items you want to return. It is essentially equivalent to:

```
>>> c.most_common(4)
[('Google', 2), ('Apple', 2), ('Amazon', 2), ('Paypal', 1)]
>>> c.most_common()[:4]
[('Google', 2), ('Apple', 2), ('Amazon', 2), ('Paypal', 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by maintaining two variables `maxi` and `maxi_value` storing the maximum element and no of times it has occured.

```
dict = {}
maxi = None
maxi_value = 0
for elem in comp:
    try:
        dict[elem] += 1
    except IndexError:
        dict[elem] = 1
    if dict[elem] > mini_value:
        mini = elem
print (maxi)
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the number of occurences of one of the top words, and then filter the whole list returned by `most_common`:

```
>>> mc = cnt.most_common()
>>> filter(lambda t: t[1] == mc[0][1], mc)
```